# Docker Javascript connection to localhost websocket problem

Tags: javascript, php, docker, docker-compose, websocket

I have a Java Spring app running on my host system. It exposes a websocket on port 8080. Websocket works correctly, tested using Postman.

Another part of my app is the PHP web app running in Docker. That website should connect to websocket running on my host machine using Javascript.
JS connection is established like this:

```
exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.113:8080/socket");
```

The problem is that when I run my docker web app, it fails to connect. On the other side, pinging 192.168.1.113 from within PHP docker container gives proper response. What might be the problem? This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nginx-cq:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    ports:
      - 11096:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: cq_php_docker
    networks:
      - default
      - dbnetwork
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ./xdebug/docker-xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
    ports:
      - 9011:9000
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:192.168.1.113"

networks:
  dbnetwork:
    external: true
```

Comment: the port number `8080` doesn't appear in your docker-compose file. the port is closed by default

Comment: Hmmm makes sense, but when i edit my docker-compose and add this 8080:8080 then my Spring app won't start complaining port is already used :)

Comment: the left side should be the host port that is `8080` and the right side should be another port number say `8090` so now when within the docker `new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.113:8090/socket");`

Comment: 8080:8090 with connection string modified still gives the same result when trying to run spring app that listens on 8080 - port in use :(

Comment: @guest86 Sooo you need to check what is using this port on your machine, for Linux `netstat -tulpn | grep :8080`

Comment: When i stop the docker container - nothing. When I start it, naturally it's using that port. Then when i start Spring app Tomcat tries to use 8080 as well

Comment: The problem seems to be that in Spring websockets must use HTTP port declared by Tomcat. I can't use port 8080 for HTTP and port 8088 for websocket connections